# How to have jar execute without main manifest attribute?

Tags: java, maven, websocket, spring-boot, jetty

I have a jar file built from a maven project. In it's pom, I have both spring boot and jetty. The purpose of my project is to implement web sockets on my website. Jetty's implementation of web sockets does not include a main method, just one class so it knows what to do when it gets web socket requests. I then tried java -jar target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, but I got the error 'no main manifest attribute.' I'm not sure why I would need one. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
My pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>myName</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo2_maven_org</id>
            <url>http://repo2.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.v20150612</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.v20150612</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax-websocket-server-impl</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.v20150612</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.0.v20150612</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My only java code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/jsr356toUpper")
public class ToUpper356Socket {
    private ArrayList<Session> sessions = new ArrayList<Session>();
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        sessions.add(session);
        System.out.println("WebSocket opened: " + session.getId());
    }
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String txt, Session session) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Message received: " + txt);
        for (Session ses : sessions){
            ses.getBasicRemote().sendText(txt);
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(CloseReason reason, Session session) {
        sessions.remove(session);
        System.out.println("Closing a WebSocket due to " + reason.getReasonPhrase());

    }
}
```

Comment: When you execute `mvn package` (or any other goal "after" that, like `mvn install`), Maven generates a manifest file. It's hard to say what could be the problem with so few details about your project. Please add your pom file so we can see the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide the mainClass value,
from [spring-boot-maven plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html)

> mainClass String  1.0 The name of the main class. If not specified the
>   first compiled class found that contains a 'main' method will be used.

inside you plugin add a configuration

```
<configuration>
        <mainClass><your main class></mainClass>
    </configuration>
```

***Or***

you can simply do something like this, maven properties

```
<properties>    
    <start-class><your main class></start-class>
</properties>
```

Comment: Tried both of these, and I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need a spring-boot starter class that provides the main method.  Something like this.  Then the spring-boot-maven-plugin will take care of the rest for you.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```